# Estimate predicted value from linear model in R

Tags: r, sas, stata, linear-regression, lsmeans

Given a regression model:

y = b0 + b1(x)

where both x and y are continuous.

After fitting the model, I'd like to estimate the predicted mean and 95%CI of y when x is at a certain value, say, 100.

In Stata, it can be achieved with margins:

```
reg y x
margins, at (x = 100)
```

In SAS, it can be done with estimate:

```
proc glm;
model y = x / clparm solution;
estimate "Test x = 100" intercept 1 x 100;
run;
```

My question is: how to achieve the same action in R? I tried the `lsmeans` package but it seems it will not work if I don't have any categorical variables in my model.

Comment: `?predict.lm` you just pass `interval="confidence"`

Comment: @bunk - If the data is outside the existing data, then a 'prediction' interval may be more appropriate.

Comment: @thelatemail indeed! thanks

Comment: It IS possible in lsmeans -- something like `lsmeans(model, "x", at = list(x = 100))`. But Ben's answer is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
predict(fit,newdata=data.frame(x=100),interval="confidence")
```

(I don't agree with @thelatemail's advice that prediction intervals are preferred; prediction intervals are specified if you want to allow for the residual error ...)

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.

Comment: Technically, the R equivalent of `margins, at (x = 100)` would be `predict(fit, newdata = within(data, x = 100), interval="confidence")` as `margins` gives an average prediction across all cases with `x` fixed to the specified value, not a prediction for a single, specific case.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a difference in the **univariate** case that the OP is asking about? @rvl, should there be a new/updated answer that references new functionality/syntax in `emmeans` ?